# Hover Disappear after one sec

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Hello**

I trying to hover on website menu and click it's inside link (only after hover its visible)

but the problem is when i hover on the menu its only visible for a second, its happening in Internet Explorer WebDriver, in other sites all working fine
what can it be ?

**What i Tried:**

- Click on menu `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='Menu']/ul/li[2]")).Click(); // Exception: element not clickable .`

**my code is:**

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
IWebElement menuHoverLink = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='Menu']/ul/li[2]"));
actions.MoveToElement(menuHoverLink);
actions.Build().Perform(); // <- appear for a sec and closed
actions.Click(); // <- doing nothing 

driver.FindElement(By.Id("inMenuLink")).Click(); // Exception: element not visible
```

Comment: why don't you try `actions.MoveToElement(menuHoverLink).click().Build().Perform();`

Comment: Still the same, appear for one sec...

Comment: may be your menu that appears upon mouse hover is getting closed upon click? you can try commenting out the line `actions.click()`, and let us know whether if it works for you...

Comment: i tried all the options with or without, click, build, perform in all combinations.. nothing works, its looks like after the hover the page is reloaded or something...

Comment: did you try doing it manually, for how much time the hover remains?

Comment: yes manually its work fine, now i see that the code driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='megaMenu']/ul/li[2]")).Click(); works too but doing the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this a known issue with the InternetExplorerDriver.

As per the [official documentation of InternetExplorerDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver)

> **Hovering Over Elements**
>
> When you attempt to hover over elements, and your physical mouse
> cursor is within the boundaries of the IE browser window, the hover
> will not work. More specifically, **the hover will appear to work for a
> fraction of a second, and then the element will revert back to its
> previous state**. The prevailing theory why this occurs is that IE is
> doing hit-testing of some sort during its event loop, which causes it
> to respond to the physical mouse position when the physical cursor is
> within the window bounds. The WebDriver development team has been
> unable to discover a workaround for this behavior of IE.

As mentioned in above issue, you should try to move your physical mouse cursor out of the IE window boundries, and then try to execute your code.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
String javaScript = "var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');" +
                    "evObj.initMouseEvent(\"mouseover\",true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);" +
                    "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);";


((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(javaScript, webElement);
```