# Solution to IEWebDriver Mouse Over issues?

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, cross-browser, mouseover, robotframework

so I have a set of cross-browser tests which involve interacting with an element that is 'invisible.'  It is on the page after a user completes the upload of a file but will only be revealed when the user hovers over it, when they do that, the option to delete appears.  This was fine until I ran it in sauce labs and noticed an issue with IE11 on Win7.  I've narrowed it down to problems with mouse actions in Internet Explorer and I'm trying to source the best solution to this problem.

At the moment the only working solution I have is to execute some javascript to make the element visible....but I dislike this a lot.  I've tried playing with the 'Simulate' keyword but with no success, again attempting mouse actions and firing click events.

Anybody have a decent suggestion to try or something which worked for them in the past?

Comment: It looks like a known [bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588639/hover-disappear-after-one-sec)

Comment: yeah I found the official documentation, I'm still surprised there's no clear workaround discussed which isn't as intrusive as my current solution.

Answer (score -1):

In java this might help you

- wait for the element to appear again
- find the element again
- perform the specific action on the element.

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 20);
  WebElement element = 
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(elementPath));    
  element = driver.findElement(elementpath);
  ```

Comment: Hi Lokesh, unfortunately this is using robot framework which is written in Python.  The issue is also that the element *never* appears due to how IE handles mouse events, therefore waiting won't do anything.  As mentioned I can use JS to amend to element properties but I see that as an overly aggressive solution.